# Finding JNDI/LDAP Connection Security Protocol

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, jndi

I'm using java (8) to connect to an LDAP-Server to get some information.
I'm doing this over SSL but I cannot figure out if my specified security protocol is actually being used....

Here is my code:

```
LdapContext ctx = null;
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable <String, String>();
try{
    env.clear();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", 5000);
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", 5000);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "myurl");
    ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
} catch(NamingException nex) {
    // Errors get treated here
}
int debug_stop = 1;
```

Its all about `Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL` in my case as the connection is successfully established. Here is some information about this paramerter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap-gl.html#protocol

I tried usind the following parameters (all within `""` of course) :

- `ssl` / `SSL`
- `starttls` / `STARTTLS`
- `SSL/STARTTLS`
- `TLSv1.1`

but I see no change at all.

I tried debugging it in Netbeans and looking at the `ctx`-variable but there is so much to look at that I cannot find the right information I'm looking for.

The thing I look at is:

ctx

- Inherited

  - defaultInitCtx

    - clnt

      - conn

        - sock

          - sess

            - protocolVersion

              - name

And this always says `TLSv1` no matter what I enter in my code above.

1) Is this the protocol that the connection is using?

2) Am I looking at the wrong variable?

3) How can I determine which protocol my established connection is using?

Another thing I found was in

ctx

- Inherited

  - defaultInitCtx

    - clnt

      - conn

        - sock

          - Inherited

            - self

              - sslContext

                - Static

                  - defaultServerSSLParams

                    - protocols

Here I found a list that says:

- `SSLv2Hello`
- `TLSv1`
- `TLSv1.1`
- `TLSv1.2`

and so I tried using `TLSv1.1` as a parameter above as well but without success...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your link (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap-gl.html), the only value for `java.naming.security.protocol`  is "ssl".

With `Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL`="ssl" :

- it opens a secure SSL/TLS connexion if the serveur supports it
- it fails with a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` otherwise

With `Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL`=any other word than "ssl", it opens a simple connection (with no SSL/TLS)

So, with the standard factory (`com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory`) and with "ssl" param, you use a SSL/TLS connexion or do nothing.

You can see a lot of details of your connection with the parameter **-Djava.net.debug=ssl** and can see which version of TLS and cipher is used by your connection.
(see http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/SSL-Socket-Communication-Debug-javax-net-debug.html)

Comment: please put code under `` to make it look like `this`

Comment: thanks for your hint to use `-Djava.net.debug=ssl` I will try that but in the oracle documentation it says also "In addition to the value listed above, a provider may support other security protocols" and I know that the server does allow TLS as well but I could not tell if the connection is actually using it

Comment: TLS is the successor of SSL. The value `ssl` is a bit confusing in `Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL`. Java will try to use the best (strongest) protocol for the connection, and in 2016, it will probably be TLS.
In the debug output, I can see I use TLS 
`%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`
despite the code with `env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");

Comment: @OlivierT where do you see that debug message?

Comment: I see it in the console, juste after the `*** ServerHello` message. You can add the ligne `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl");` in you code instead of the VM argument

Comment: @OlivierT I did add the line `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl");` to my code but cannot see any output in any of the tomcat log files and I dont see anything in netbeans logging views either

Comment: finally found the info you described, but I had to add `-Djavax.net.debug=handshake,ssl` as my VM Options in my Tomcat Server